# asp.net FindControl on unbound gridview or repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater, findcontrol

I have some user controls that contain asp.net GridViews and Repeaters and before binding data to them, i have to run some checks. I need to know whether certain controls exist in a TemplateField or ItemTemplate. Of course i cannot do .Row[0].FindControl, because there are no rows at this stage.

Comment: The templates don't instantiate if there is no databind call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling Databind, you cannot check any of the databound templates for controls.

Not sure what your situation is, but perhaps you can loop through your data and validate there?

Comment: So, you can add template fields programmatically, but you cannot do anything with the existing ones?

Comment: I did it by parsing the usercontrol as a textfile. That worked fine :)